# Adding information to xml with help of xslt

Tags: java, xslt, xpath

It's the task:

"The page contains ADD button to add new entity on the next page and after SAVE button has been pressed you make again XSLT transformation to get XML with new entity, save it and generate in the response list of entities.
During addition of entity call the JAVA code using xalan extension to validate fields.
PS You can not use jsp"

I don't understand how to do it. Can you help me understand this?

Comment: It's sad you don't understand your own homework. Should have attended those classes. Come back, when you are stuck with something, and have a specific question.

Comment: I taught it myself, it's like hobby.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dmitry, my friend, I know you know Russian. Try this link out - http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/x-xjavaforum5/index.html Also, could you please clarify, why do you have to use XSLT?